# How can I publish MrSID files in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, mrsid

I need to publish MrSID files using geoserver 2.1.4.

I am unable to even get the plugin to add the store in geoserver.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

GeoServer supports MrSID through the GDAL Image Format plugin but i have seen @[iant](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/79/iant) comments [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/6519/3071) as:

> I wrote a simple tutorial on how to build a pyramid data store in
>   GeoServer
>   (http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/data/bluemarble/bluemarble.html),
>   it works with png imagery but providing you have a MrSid licence I
>   believe all the tools work the same way. Once you have the data in
>   GeoServer you can set up GeoWebCache in front of it (in version 2.1)
>   you don't even need to install anything extra. By default GeoWebCache
>   will cache in 4326 and 900913 so there is no need to reproject your
>   data if you don't want to.

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Your link is dead. You want to repost your tutorial here?